# Uipath Chrome "This type of file can harm your computer. Do you want to keep [filename] anyways?"

Tags: google-chrome-extension, automation, browser-automation, rpa, uipath

I'm running Uipath Studio 2020.10.2 and having an issue with the selecting to 'Keep' a file in Chrome browser after getting the message: "This type of file can harm your computer. Do you want to keep [filename] anyways?"
Would anyone have a fix without having to disabling Safe Browsing?

Comment: What is the question. You want to hit Enter there?

Comment: So it doesn't work when I hit enter. The window has focus so I figured I could just click into it but with the chrome extension it doesn't seem to allow me to locate the selector. as a work around I used an OCR to locate where to click, then built an anchor, and used those to select the correct place to click. Not totally ideal but it seems stable enough. Just wondering if there's a better way to do that.

Comment: Can you show some images? Because I have a similar case in our company where it does work properly with giving focus and hitting enter. Maybe you not setting focus correctly?

Comment: Sorry I can't since it's my work pc. What version of UiPath are you using? I wonder if there's an incompatibility. I tried removing the add-in and reinstalling but that doesn't seem to help.